# JqueryUI - Working with widgets of unknown type with common base

Tags: jquery-ui

I have created a JQueryUI widget which is used as a base for several current and future widgets.  My web page is using an unknown number of these derived widgets which are of unknown types.  The only thing I really know is that they all derived from my base widget.

My problem is this I need to call a method defined in the base widget without knowing what the actual derived widget is.  I can get the list of elements that have the derived widgets applied to them, but I cannot figure out how to get a reference to the base widget.

Assuming my base widget is called "base", I tried  $(element).base('instance') but it returned 'undefined'.

I am using Using JQueryUI 1.11.2 and jQuery 1.11.3.

Comment: You can't do this, not cleanly at least, due to the nature of prototypal inheritance. Odds are you can get something better by changing how the widgets are modelled. Could you include more details about what your goal is?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it cannot be done.   jQueryUI will not allow you to obtain the base widget from an instance of a derived widget.

The workaround I settled on was to use a custom event instead.  When I create an instance of my widget it binds the method I want to invoke to a custom event.  When I want to invoke the method I trigger the custom event on the element associated with the widget.  This works for my particular use case but might not work for others.